# list filtering in repository in clean architeture

Tags: sqlalchemy, clean-architecture

I'm trying to implement repository layer of clean architecture based on SqlAlchemy. For now I'm trying to figure out how to work with filtering in different cases. The code:

```
import logging
from typing import Literal

from faker import Faker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, ForeignKey, select, String, BinaryExpression
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Mapped, mapped_column, relationship, Session, selectinload

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")

fake = Faker()
logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


ContactTypeCode = Literal["email", "phone"]


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name: Mapped[str]
    last_name: Mapped[str]

    contacts: Mapped[list["Contact"]] = relationship(back_populates="user")


class ContactType(Base):
    __tablename__ = "contact_types"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    code: Mapped[ContactTypeCode]

    contacts: Mapped[list["Contact"]] = relationship(back_populates="contact_type")


class Contact(Base):
    __tablename__ = "contacts"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    contact_type_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("contact_types.id"))
    value: Mapped[str]
    user_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("users.id"))

    user: Mapped["User"] = relationship(back_populates="contacts")
    contact_type: Mapped["ContactType"] = relationship(back_populates="contacts")


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


def create_user():
    return User(first_name=fake.first_name(), last_name=fake.last_name())


def prepare(session):
    # create user with contacts
    user_w_contacts = create_user()

    contact_type = ContactType(code="phone")

    contacts = [
        Contact(value=fake.phone_number(), user=user_w_contacts, contact_type=contact_type)
        for _ in range(2)
    ]
    user_w_contacts.contacts = contacts

    # create user without contacts
    user_wo_contacts = create_user()

    session.add_all([user_w_contacts, user_wo_contacts])
    session.commit()


class UsersRepository:
    base_model = User

    def __init__(self, session):
        self._session = session

    def filter(self, *whereclause: tuple[BinaryExpression]):
        stmt = select(self.base_model).where(*whereclause)
        users = self._session.scalars(stmt).all()

        return users

    # def get_users_with_contacts(self):
    #     stmt = select(self.base_model).join(self.base_model.contacts)
    #     users = self._session.scalars(stmt).all()
    #
    #     return users
    #
    # def get_users_with_contacts_selected(self, *whereclause: tuple[BinaryExpression]):
    #     stmt = select(self.base_model).options(selectinload(self.base_model.contacts)).where(*whereclause)
    #     users = self._session.scalars(stmt).all()
    #
    #     return users
    #
    # def get_users_without_contacts(self, *whereclause: tuple[BinaryExpression]):
    #     pass
    #
    # another combinations of joining, options, filters, etc
```

According to clean architecture should I have for every case separate list filter method? I see it convenient for maintaining and testing. Or should I develop single `filter` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In his book "Clean Architecture" Uncle Bob writes:

> Between the use case interactors and the database are the database gateways. These gateways are polymorphic interfaces that contain methods for every create, read, update, or delete operation that can be performed by the application on the database. For example, if the application needs to know the last names of all the users who logged in yesterday, then the UserGateway interface will have a method named getLastNamesOfUsersWhoLoggedInAfter that takes a Date as its argument and returns a list of last names.

"Database gateways" here refers to "repositories".

So if you want to follow Clean Architecture very strict you would create separate "filter" methods, one for each use case. This would not only allow you to completely hide the database schema but would also allow you to create perfectly optimized database queries.

For further details on how to implement repositories in Clean Architecture see: https://youtu.be/pfhDO_hZixw

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to have a dedicated repository for each use case. This is also known as the interfaces segregation principle. As a result you might also have multiple filter methods. If you want to share code between these repositories you can extract it to another class that both use.

But there is another issue not mentioned yet. In the clean architecture a repository returns entities (domain objects). The objects your repository returns contain ORM info and therefore implementation details of the repository, relational mapping in your case.

The repository should return entities that only contain domain logic in order to make them easier to test. If your "entities" contains ORM info you violate the dependency inversion principle, because a more abstract concept like domain logic then depends on low level details like ORM mapping.

You can also see that violation when you look at the `filter` method's parameters. The `whereclause` parameter exposes details to the client. Since repositories are used by use cases it means that a use case, usually called interactor, must pass the `whereclause` to the repository and therefore knows the details of the implementation. In your case the interactor is bound to sqlalchemy.

I'm not very familiar with python yet. But I guess your code contains a similar  issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42175497/can-hibernate-business-objects-be-used-as-entities-in-a-clean-architecture/68600629#68600629).

You might also want to watch [Robert C Martin - Clean Architecture, NDC 2012 (53:53 - 54:18)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nltqi7ODZTM&t=3209s). Uncle Bob talked to C# developers and therefore talks about NHibernate, which is a ORM for .NET. But if you replace NHibernate with sqlalchemy, it might make sense to python developers as well.